# Having space in front of logged messages in logback

Tags: java, logback

My Logback pattern in `logback.xml` file as follows

```
<pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} ${LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN:-%5p} %yellow([%X{Auth-Scopes:-},%X{Auth-Principal:-},%X{Auth-Organization:-}]) %magenta(${PID:-}) --- [%15.15t] %cyan(%-40.40logger{39}) : %m %n ${LOG_EXCEPTION_CONVERSION_WORD:-%xEx}</pattern>
```

My problem is there is space in front of log lines from above pattern as follows

`2021-08-18 03:40:00.017 DEBUG [test-service,,,] [,,] 1 --- [test-7] a.b.c.Test  : Test`

I am still trying to figure out what this cause for some time. Any help would be really appreciated .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last parameter causes the problem.
You can try this one;

```
        <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} ${LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN:-%5p} %yellow([%X{Auth-Scopes:-},%X{Auth-Principal:-},%X{Auth-Organization:-}]) %magenta(${PID:-}) --- [%15.15t] %cyan(%-40.40logger{39}) : %m ${LOG_EXCEPTION_CONVERSION_WORD:-%xEx} %n</Pattern>
```